# Can a windows driver operate without a client?

Tags: windows, driver, hid

Is it possible to write an HID driver that performs some operation from device input without needing an application in the user layer?

The [Microsoft docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj126193%28v=vs.85%29) describe a Client application in the user layer interacting with the HID architecture in the kernel via HID.dll. Does the kernel-level driver code still operate when no client is present?

If this is possible, what types of operations are permitted? Could the driver, say, pipe information from the device down a UDP stream?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  If you can't do everything you need from the interrupt routine, a kernel-mode driver can launch one or more system threads when it starts up (i.e., from [DriverEntry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff544113%28v=vs.85%29)) using [PsCreateSystemThread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff559932%28v=vs.85%29) and then act as its own client.

Of course, you can only perform operations that are possible from kernel mode.  For network operations, the [Winsock Kernel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff556958%28v=vs.85%29) API is available.  It is not entirely clear from the documentation whether this interface is available to all drivers or only to network drivers, but if necessary you could always install a network filter driver alongside your own driver.

Note, however, that it might be easier to install a system service to act as a user-mode component.  You should be able to do this from a device-specific co-installer as [described here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff728854%28v=vs.85%29).

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Thanks for the detailed answer.